# Copying data from master sheet to other sheets in workbook by vba code

Tags: vba

Hi I am using below code to copy data conditionally from one sheet to other sheets in a workbook. There are different conditions for each sheet. For sheet updated if column AQ4 in sheet employee data is blank and column BA4 contains text as "working" then copy data of that row from sheet employee data to sheet updated. For sheet executive if column G4 contains text as "executive" and column BA4 contains text as "working" then copy data of that row from sheet employee data to sheet executive. For sheet supervisor if column G4 contains text as "supervisor" and column BA4 contains text as "working" then copy data of that row from sheet employee data to sheet supervisor. For sheet workmen if column G4 contains text  as "workmen" and column BA4 contains text as "working" then copy data of that row from sheet employee data to sheet workmen. For sheet transferred if column AQ is non blank and column BA4 contains text as "transferred" then copy data from sheet employee data to sheet transferred.

This code is neither working nor displaying any error.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, str1 As Variant, str2 As Variant, shAry As Variant, c As Range, i As Long, rng As Range
    Set sh = Sheets("Employee Data")
    str1 = Array("", ",", "Executive", "Supervisor", "Workmen")
    str2 = Array("Working", "Transferred", "Working", "Working", "Working")
    shAry = Array("Updated", "Transferred", "Executive", "Supervisor", "Workmen")
    For i = LBound(str1) To UBound(str1)
        If i = 0 Or i = s1 Then
            Sheets(shAry(i)).Range("B4:AX20000").ClearContents
            With sh.UsedRange.Offset(2).Resize(sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2)
                .AutoFilter 51, str2(i)
                .AutoFilter 41, str1(i)
            End With
        Else
            Sheets(shAry(i)).Range("B4:AX20000").ClearContents
            With sh.UsedRange.Offset(2).Resize(sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2)
                .AutoFilter 51, str2(i)
                .AutoFilter 6, str1(i)
            End With
        End If
        Set rng = Intersect(sh.Range("B:AX"), sh.UsedRange.Offset(3)).Resize(sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3)
        On Error Resume Next
        rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets(shAry(i)).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2)
        On Error GoTo 0
        sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `s1` is never declared or assigned.  Is it a global somewhere?  You also never use the variable `c`.

Comment: no it is not declared as global variable

Comment: Is it supposed to be something else then?  Right now it's just an empty `Variant`.